# Error invalid at parse formdata request at nodejs server

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js

I am working with a simple file upload from client to server . Below is what i tried.

```
    eReaderBook.controller('browseCtrl',['$scope',"$http",function($scope,$http){
$scope.fileName ="";
$scope.imageName ="";
    $scope.uploadFile = function(){

        var data1 = new FormData();
        data1.append('input_file_name', $('#fileName').prop('files')[0]);
        data1.append('input_image_name', $('#imageName').prop('files')[0]);
        if($scope.fileName!="" && $scope.imageName!="")
        {

            $http({
                url: '/upload',
                method: "POST",
                data: data1
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                    console.log("success")
            }, 
            function(response) { // optional
                    console.log("failed")
            }); 
        } 
    };
}])
```

node .js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer());
app.post('/upload',function(req,res)
{
   console.log("aaa");  
   res.send("hi")
 });
```

But when i send request to nodejs server it throws an error Error: invalid json
    at parse (d:\MeanTest\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)

What i am doing wrong here...

Comment: try using just this  - app.use(bodyParser);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `data` you are passing is not a `valid json` and so `bodyParser.json()` while processing, will throw an `error`.

You can use `bodyParser.raw(options)` to use as a `middleware`. The `bodyParser.raw()` returns middleware that parses all bodies as a Buffer.

For reference: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: @bharath: Happy to help :-)